# What's the difference between call PrintWritter print() many times or add string and then just print one time? Which is better?

Tags: java, string, performance

In servlet, usually people output something as below.

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.print("<html>");
out.print("<head>");
out.print("</head>");
out.print("<body>");
...Many lines here...
out.print("</body>");
out.print("</html>");
```

Write in different lines because it is much more convenient for reading and modifying in the future if needed, but I'm think is code like next valid (common) ?

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
String outView = "<html>"
  + "<head>"
  + "</head>"
  + "<body>"
  ...Many lines here...
  + "</body>"
  + "</html>";
out.print(outView);
```

What's the difference? And how's the performance of each one?

Comment: method calls are expensive, I would try to minimize the number of method calls you do

Comment: Here you have to compare two things:
1. The number of times you call out.print
2. The string operation (+ string + string + ...)
You have to compare the performance of these two operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form my own  personal experience in JSP. I know `out.print()` is better than `concatenating strings` .

You might have worked with `BufferedOutputStream` in file `IO` . Where you write your data to the file `(which actually gets written in a BUFFER)` and whenever you think the data should be made permanent, you call `flush()` . And your data gets written to the file. Several times I have been left bewildered, why my file is empty. Then at the end I found that , I did not call `flush()` .

The same way `out.print()` works. `out` writes the data to a buffer , there are several `functions` to control its behaviour. So every time you call `out.print()` it adds the string to the buffer . And this fast as compared to `String concatentation` .

While we concatenate Strings , as Strings are `immutable` , new Strings are created. 
So for this

`"<head>"
  + "</head>"
  + "<body>"`

Total `5` String objects are created.

1. `"<head>"`
2. `"</head>"`
3. `"<body>"`
4. `"<head></head>"`
5. `"<head></head><body>"`

And this goes on until all of your Strings are `concatenated`.

But in the case of `out.print()` only `3` String objects are created.

I was working on a JSP , I was creating a `Table` in JSP, at my work. `Don't blame me , not my fault, this is the way they work here :)` .

I replaced String addition with `StringBuffer` and it made the JSP faster . Earlier I thought it is slow because it is accessing data and simultaneously creating table, that's why it is slow, But problem was `String addition` . So from my experience always go for `out.print()` .

If you really need to create an output before you write it. Use `StringBuffer` and while writing to the response use `toString()` to convert it back to String . It will save a lot of time.

String concatenation gives a clear picture several times, use it while developing, but for production use `StringBuffer` . It is going to be a lot faster, depending on amount of concatenation, you are doing in code.

Answer (score 2):

This question reminds me of this great blog post on micro-optimization: [The sad tragedy of micro-optimization](http://blog.codinghorror.com/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater/)

Basically, it boils down to the notion that you shouldn't worry about tiny optimization differences like this, but always go for the option that has the best readibility. This will give the best profit in the long run, because it will increase the managability of your code. It will be easier to maintain, reuse and enhance.

And from this point of view: both methods you mention are pretty terrible, because they involve directly printing html from servlets. This makes the html hard to read and debug. You should maintain the html in separate files, or use some kind of templating mechanism like jsp or jsf.

Comment: Thank you, I know it is not good to print html from servlet, but can you explain me more how out.print() actually do in a servlet?

Comment: @Quantin - Use JSPs or a templating engine to generate the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Well as far as i remember there is something known as string pool in JVM . It means all the strings `1."<head>" 2. "</head>" 3. "<body>"` .. etc are getting stored there . It means if you have somethings like

```
String v1="head";
String v2="head";
```

both v1 & v2 will refer to the same object . These object's are eligible for garbage collection if there are no references to them . Now the problem i think (i have never tried it) is if your "outView" becomes so large that it does not fit in the string pool you will get outofmemeoryexception ... where as "response.getWriter" returns a object that has internal buffering , it uses heap space for internal buffering thus it is better to use  "response.getWriter" approach.

Comment: yes v1 and v2 will refer to the same object, but actually `String v3 = "hhh" + "ddd"` JVM will straightly store "hhhddd" into string pool, and then v3 just refers to it. If, only if I write a large string v4 which adds many strings(html tags) by using + operator and "", without adding other java variables. Then print it one time, will it be different compares to call out.print() many times? I don't understand well about how out.print() actually do to the response

Comment: Yes .. as after String v3 will go out of scope it will be eligible for garbage collection ... so there is no problem in this approach also . "KISS" => keep it simple , simple things work.